Using action to break dialogue in the middle of a sentence
The sentence is:

"The man will arrive in about…” He checked his wristwatch. “…four minutes."

I'm wondering if the ellipses should be em dash, and how the punctuation should be around the action. I think the correct way would be:

"The man will arrive in about…” he checked his wristwatch, “…four minutes."

I know the easy thing would be to move the action to the beginning of the sentence, but I see this a lot and always wonder what the correct format is.

I think it's just a matter of whatever your chosen style guide recommends. But I seriously doubt any style guide would endorse capitalizing He in such a "parenthetical interjection".

...quite a few instances of the sequence but he paused I will feature he paused as a break in reported speech, so you can look at them. Mostly, I see ellipses (three dots), or commas.

There is today a Staccato. Style. Of periods. I can picture this: "The man will arrive in about." He checked his wristwatch.“Four minutes." Any style that shows thought, considers the reader, and displays consistency has plenty going for it. Period.

@YosefBaskin: I can go with that. Periods and commas, they're both "light punctuation", which is the modern style. Ellipses can be a bit distractingly fussy, imho

I'd use a modification of Yosef's suggestion: "The man will arrive in about...." He checked his wristwatch. “Four minutes."  I don't like the full stop for a pregnant pause.

@EdwinAshworth Smooth move. The line is now funnier, too.

Ellipses often suggest someone's voice trailing off. Which I assume isn't happening here.
